# PHP JSON pass as query string

Tags: php, json, query-string

I have few status return into json_encode object based on certain circumstances.

```
if(verify == 1)
    $data = array('status'=>'SUCCESS', 'points'=>$points, 'user'=>$user);

if(verify == 2)
    $data = array('status'=>'INACTIVE');

if(verify == 0)
    $data = array('status'=>'FAILED');

$data_str = json_encode($data);
```

I need `$data_str` to add as query string, when it redirect to hitter URL, such as: `https://www.example.com/members?status=SUCCESS&points=2500&user=albert@hotmail.com` OR `https://www.example.com/members?status=INACTIVE`

How could `$data_str` to be pass as query string?

Comment: You can use a foreach loop to loop through key-value pairs of $data and construct your query string. Don't forget to set rawurlencode for the value part.

Comment: use `http_build_query()` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `PHP` function `http_build_query` to achieve this and you never need to use anything else like `foreach` loop:

```
if($verify == 1)
    $data = array('status'=>'SUCCESS', 'points'=>$points, 'user'=>$user);

if($verify == 2)
    $data = array('status'=>'INACTIVE');

if($verify == 0)
    $data = array('status'=>'FAILED');

$url = https://www.example.com/members?.http_build_query($data);
```

**EDIT**

Here is [demo](https://3v4l.org/fYHVQ)

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be :

1. Turn your array into a string using : 
   [implode](http://php.net/implode)
2. Make it ready for an URL using : [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$verify = 1;
$points = 2500;
$user = 'albert';

if($verify == 1)
    $data = array('status'=>'SUCCESS', 'points'=>$points, 'user'=>$user);

if($verify == 2)
    $data = array('status'=>'INACTIVE');

if($verify == 0)
    $data = array('status'=>'FAILED');

//$data_str = json_encode($data);

$qryStr = array();
foreach($data as  $key => $val){
    $qryStr[] = $key."=".$val;
}
echo $url = 'https://www.example.com/'.implode("&", $qryStr); //https://www.example.com/status=SUCCESS&points=2500&user=albert
```

OR use `http_build_query()`.

```
echo $url = 'https://www.example.com/'.http_build_query($data); //https://www.example.com/status=SUCCESS&points=2500&user=albert
```